# Composer fails to resolve to installable set of packages on using "install" but not "update"

Tags: php, silex, composer-php

Background: I set up a new project, on my desktop machine, with Silex and set up my composer.json file with the dependencies that I need. I ran "composer.phar install" successfully on the desktop without any problems.

I switched over to my laptop to work on the project some more, cloned the git repo to the laptop, and tried to do a "composer.phar install" but received this message:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
```

So I did a "composer.phar update" instead, and it worked, but I did not want my composer.lock file updated.

Is anybody else having this issue? If not, can somebody please explain what I'm doing wrong?

Edit: I thought I should probably come back to this and update the question. I haven't had this issue in quite some time. I don't know if it's an update to composer that has fixed it (people might have to comment to let me know if they're still experiencing this issue) or if now that I've learned more about composer, I'm just doing things in a way that I don't encounter this. Either way I've not seen this message in nearly a year and a half unless my package spec in composer.json was actually broken.

Comment: Can I ask when you cloned the project did it include the vendor folder and also the composer.lock file? Usually when I am changing machines I have no vendor folder or .lock file committed and the first thing I'd do is run composer.phar install

Comment: I did not have the vendor folder in the repo, but I do include the lock file so that all the people who check out the project and install dependencies are on the same version.

Comment: `Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.` isn't full error message. Can you provide exact package conflicts, which are displayed after that?

Comment: Could you please provide your composer.json dependencies list? Are you using private repositories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hum, my guess would be that you are using a library which is based on a branch (`dev-master`, `dev-branch-name` or `branch-name@dev`), on which the maintainer would have forced a push recently (to rebase the branch for example).

Whenever possible, try to use stable branches (branches with a version which is linked to a tag (v1.0.0, 1.0.*, etc.). If you don't know where to look at, you should look for your package on [Packagist](https://packagist.org), and use a version which does not start by `dev-`, or uses a `@dev` modifier to set the minimum-stability to `dev`.

Of course, it is sometimes unavoidable. But in this case, you can always ask the maintainer of the library to tag a version. :)

My second guess would be that you have different libraries versions on your machine. Take the `symfony/icu` library, for example. Depending on the version of Icu that you have on your machine, and depending on the fact that you enabled or the fact that you have the intl extension installed on your machine or not, you may run into these issues.
As composer will try to match the composer.lock with your old machine, the dependencies won't resolve as the locked packages will need a dependency that your system doesn't have.
A simple way to fix this is simply to install the needed extension.

Comment: It's been quite a long time since I've had this problem at all. I was also very young in my usage of Composer. I am thinking this is probably exactly the case. Ever since I started using tagged versions, which to be honest is probably the stabler way to work, I haven't had this issue. I know Composer is supposed to manage this via the lock file, but I found that I had much more success with real tagged versions, even if I use wildcard version specification (i.e. "1.*" or "1.1.*"). Thanks to everybody who replied.